# Reconstruction of image inline section.

Tags: html, css, xcode

Can someone please show me how to rebuild this section using html and css. I have tried a few times and cant quite get it right. I just need to be shown once and Ill catch on from there. Currently, I am using Squarespace so can just drag content onto the page but I need to re insert this using just html and css. Thanks for the help

You can get the text from my homepage www.jobspark.ca

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is using a responsive grid system. If you are new to html/css it would be perhaps a bit much to write this on your own. I would suggest you use some sort of css framework.

There are many out there, but the one I prefer is [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), which is very popular and thus very well supported. The [grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) they use is very solid and responsive, i use it all the time! You can even customize the framework on their site to only include the pieces you need (to prevent to much overhead), or download the source (.less) files and edit and compile them yourself (it seems harder then it is, they are well documented!)

For the screenshot you provided, the html with bootstrap classes would look something like this:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>

   <div class='row-fluid'>
      <article class='span4'>
         <img src='...' alt='...'/>
         <h2>The title</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
         <a href='...'>Read more...</a>
      </article>

      <article class='span4'>
         ...
      </article>

      <article class='span4'>
         ...
      </article>

  </div>
</div>
```